# Pointer dereferencing in Julia (unsafe_load(ptr) works but unsafe_wrap(Array, ptr, 1) segfaults)

Tags: pointers, julia, dereference

I'm trying to dereference pointer with `unsafe_load` and `unsafe_wrap`. I found out that `unsafe_load` works just nice, however `unsafe_wrap` crashes in case of dereferencing pointer to mutable struct. Toy example:

```
[mutable] struct Wrapper
    data::Int
end

some = Wrapper(1)
ptr = convert(Ptr{Wrapper}, Base.Libc.malloc(sizeof(Wrapper)))
unsafe_store!(ptr, some)

unsafe_load(ptr) # returns Wrapper(1)
unsafe_wrap(Array, ptr, 1) # segfaults if Wrapper is mutable, works fine if not
```

And I need exactly `unsafe_wrap` as it does not make a copy (I need to perform some operations in-place in allocated by `malloc` memory). Why does it segfault?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/advice-on-using-unsafe-wrap-to-view-integers-as-atomic-integers/67918/8)

Vector of mutable structs is a vector of pointers i.e.

```
mutable struct Wrapper
    data::Int
end

a = Wrapper(1)
b = [a, a]
a.data = 2
b # is now Wrapper[Wrapper(2), Wrapper(2)]
```

So memory layout of `Int` and `Wrapper` are not the same.

Comment: I was about to comment that I suspected the issue was that `sizeof` counts the fields' sizes regardless of whether the struct is mutable or not, so it cannot be used to find the memory the struct takes up as a Vector element or another struct's field, such as that of `Ptr`. However, then I had a thought: pointers are `Int`-sized, so `sizeof` would seem to accidentally be correct because your struct's fields are also `Int`-sized. Could you explain how the segfault occurs if `malloc` is accidentally right?