# Pointer dereferencing in Julia and writing directly into memory

Tags: pointers, julia, dereference

This question continues story of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70282037/pointer-dereferencing-in-julia-unsafe-loadptr-works-but-unsafe-wraparray-pt/70282494?noredirect=1#comment124240595_70282494)

For some reason I'd like to manually manage memory in my program. So I want to allocate memory, work with it, and free it. The first and the last are quite easy. However there are some troubles with pointer dereferencing.

Suupose I have such a struct

```
mutable struct Point
    x::Float64
    y::Float64
end
```

I'd like to allocate some memory and store my Point there. In fact I could just say `point = Point(0.,0.)` but this prevents me from manually freeing up allocated memory and lets me rely on gc. So I write

```
ptr = convert(Ptr{Point}, Base.Libc.malloc(sizeof(Point))) # N.B. sizeof(Point) == 16
```

And at this point I want to write into memory pointer by ptr. I found some hacky ways to do it.

1. Use `unsafe_store!`. This method is not good for me, because I have to allocate memory for object to be written (`Point(0.,0.)`) and only after that copy it into `ptr`.

```
unsafe_store!(ptr, Point(0.,0.))
```

2. Use `unsafe_wrap`. This could be a good idea however I cannot just wrap a piece of memory into array of mutable types. That's because... array of mutable structs contains only sequential pointers to this structs, not the structs themselves. So because `Point` has two fields of type `Int`, I can wrap with type `Tuple{Float64,Float64}` and then assign values inside of wrapped array. But I also have to store `(0.,0.)` somewhere, and it's also just copying. And of course I cannot assign to fields of immutable type, so on the one hand I cannot wrap around mutable type, on the other, I cannot modify immutable (and on the third hand I cannot reinterpret them into each other)

```
ptr2 = convert(Ptr{Tuple{Float64,Float64}}, ptr)
arr = unsafe_wrap(Array, ptr2, 1)
arr[1] = (0.,0.)
```

3. Finally I can brutally convert everything to primitive types and this really allows avoid additional allocating and copying. And at this point it's time to ask myself a question, what for do I need the declaration of type `Point` if I'm working with it internals, guts and bones, directly. (Means I wanted something like `p.x = p.y = 0.`)

```
ptr3 = convert(Ptr{Int}, ptr)
arr = unsafe_wrap(Array, ptr3, 2)
arr[1] = arr[2] = 0.
```

4. The least hackish and the least working (not working at all) method. I found such a good function, called `unsafe_pointer_to_objref` and at first sight it should do all the bussines. But. It doesn't. It works quite strange. As it is said in [docs (source code)](http://unsafe_pointer_to_objref(p::Ptr)%20Convert%20a%20%60Ptr%60%20to%20an%20object%20reference.%20Assumes%20the%20pointer%20refers%20to%20a%20valid%20heap-allocated%20Julia%20object.%20If%20this%20is%20not%20the%20case,%20undefined%20behavior%20results,%20hence%20this%20function%20is%20considered%20%22unsafe%22%20and%20should%20be%20used%20with%20care.)

> ```
> unsafe_pointer_to_objref(p::Ptr)
> ```
>
> Convert a `Ptr` to an
> object reference. Assumes the pointer refers to a valid heap-allocated
> Julia object. If this is not the case, undefined behavior results,
> hence this function is considered "unsafe" and should be used with
> care.

So I have a heap-allocated `Point`, with ptr pointing on it, I can even `unsafe_load` value of it (`unsafe_load` makes a copy, so it is not the solution), and I should be able to make something like

```
point = unsafe_pointer_to_objref(ptr)
```

But this leads to

```
Please submit a bug report with steps to reproduce this fault, and any error messages that follow (in their entirety). Thanks.
Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at 0x278d238 -- typekeyvalue_hash at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jltypes.c:1160 [inlined]
lookup_typevalue at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jltypes.c:722
in expression starting at none:0
typekeyvalue_hash at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jltypes.c:1160 [inlined]
lookup_typevalue at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jltypes.c:722
jl_inst_arg_tuple_type at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\jltypes.c:1589
jl_f_tuple at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:786 [inlined]
jl_f_tuple at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:781
indexed_iterate at .\pair.jl:37 [inlined]
indexed_iterate at .\pair.jl:37
jfptr_indexed_iterate_29996.clone_1 at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
print_response at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\REPL\src\REPL.jl:281
#45 at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\REPL\src\REPL.jl:275
jfptr_YY.45_50669.clone_1 at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
with_repl_linfo at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\REPL\src\REPL.jl:508
print_response at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\REPL\src\REPL.jl:273
do_respond at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\REPL\src\REPL.jl:844
jfptr_do_respond_48815.clone_1 at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1788 [inlined]
jl_f__call_latest at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\builtins.c:757
#invokelatest#2 at .\essentials.jl:716 [inlined]
invokelatest at .\essentials.jl:714 [inlined]                                                                                                                                                                      run_interface at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\REPL\src\LineEdit.jl:2493
jfptr_run_interface_49569.clone_1 at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
run_frontend at C:\buildbot\worker\package_win64\build\usr\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\REPL\src\REPL.jl:1230
#49 at .\task.jl:423
jfptr_YY.49_48790.clone_1 at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.7.0\lib\julia\sys.dll (unknown line)
jl_apply at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1788 [inlined]
start_task at /cygdrive/c/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\task.c:877
Allocations: 2721 (Pool: 2712; Big: 9); GC: 0
```

However it works good in pair with `pointer_from_objref` (which returns `Ptr{Nothing}`, so I think `unsafe_pointer_to_objref` works good only for Julia-owned objects

```
a === unsafe_pointer_to_objref(pointer_from_objref(a))
```

Finally it seems that PointerArithmetic.jl uses `unsafe_load` to dereference pointer, that is not the solution due to mentioned above reason.

So there are 2 questions:

**Main:** How to dereference pointer on a mutable struct and obtain object located in the place that pointer points on?

Not main: why does not `unsafe_pointer_to_objref` give a result and what for does it exist?

Comment: Why are you tagging with "c"?

Comment: Julia is more safe-by-default (e.g. gc, bounds checking), and there many complicated and explicit ways of doing limited unsafety. I think it would be simpler to do manual memory management in C and use Julia's C interface to call C functions and access C data. I've read a few issues about gc latency, and the general direction of those discussions is compiler improvements, very much not manual control.

Comment: @DanielWalker, because that's Julian C interface, and most of functions from questions are written in C

Comment: @BatWannaBe,  I want to allocate memory for Julian structures and use the power of Julian type system. The most complicated solution I see is using Julia to generate appropriate C code and then use it with `ccall`. Maybe there's a package for it?

Comment: Yeah, working in Julia has its perks, but heap allocation in Julia is necessarily handled by the gc for memory safety, and it'll involve anything that isn't an isbitstype. Most approaches to avoid the gc seems to be preallocating all the non-isbitstypes at the start and then spending the rest of the program only (stack-) allocating isbitstypes or mutating the preallocated non-isbitstypes. If manual memory management of non-isbitstypes was feasible in pure Julia, people would do that to dodge the gc, instead.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not requiring a C interface for anything but memory allocation, but do not want the garbage collector to manage your structs, why not just preallocate your own heap?

Consider

```
struct MyStruct
    i::Int
    j::Float64
    MyStruct(i = 0, j = 0.0) = new(0, 0.0)
end

const heapofMyStruct = [MyStruct() for _ in 1:1000]

m = heapofMyStruct[1]
```

You will need to keep track of where you are "allocating" the next item in your heap, but heapofMyStruct should not be garbage collected in use.

Comment: But if I need MyStruct to be mutable, then my heap will be just a vector of pointers to allocated somewhere MyStructs, which is not good